# WebGL Why does it render a grayscale texture?

Tags: c#, blazor, webgl, .net-5

I have a problem with a texture to render on a plane. I am using webgl for blazor server app and use net5 for backend.

So what I am doing?

1. I read an image out of a file (this file contains a lot images) + this is working great so far. I return an int aray.
2. I create a texture out of it.
3. I render it to a plane.

**Problem: It is rendered in grayscale instead colors and I don't know why.**

[image]

And it should look like this:
[image]

Vertex Shader:

```
attribute vec3 position;
attribute vec3 normal;
attribute vec2 uv;
uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 projection;
varying vec3 vNormal;
varying vec2 vUv;

void main() {
    vUv = uv;
    vNormal = (model * vec4(normal, 0.)).xyz;
    gl_Position = projection * model * vec4(position, 1.);
}
```

Fragment Shader:

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision highp float;
#endif

uniform vec3 lightDirection;
uniform float ambientLight;
uniform sampler2D diffuse;
varying vec3 vNormal;
varying vec2 vUv;

void main() {
    float lightness = -clamp(dot(normalize(vNormal), normalize(lightDirection)), -1., 0.);
    lightness = ambientLight + (1. - ambientLight) * lightness;
    gl_FragColor = vec4(texture2D(diffuse, vUv).rgb * lightness, 1);
}
```

And this the function I built:

```
var gl = await this._canvasReference.CreateWebGLAsync(new WebGLContextAttributes
                {
                    PreserveDrawingBuffer = true,
                    PowerPreference = WebGLContextAttributes.POWER_PREFERENCE_HIGH_PERFORMANCE
                });

                await gl.ClearColorAsync(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.3f, 1);
                await gl.EnableAsync(EnableCap.DEPTH_TEST);
                await gl.ClearAsync(BufferBits.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | BufferBits.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
                await gl.EnableAsync(EnableCap.CULL_FACE);
                await gl.FrontFaceAsync(FrontFaceDirection.CCW);
                await gl.CullFaceAsync(Face.BACK);


                //Init the shaders     
                _shaderProgram = await ShaderProgram.InitShaderProgram(
                gl,
                await File.ReadAllTextAsync("includes/shaders/basic.vert"),
                await File.ReadAllTextAsync("includes/shaders/basic.frag"),
                new List<string>() { "position", "normal", "uv" },
                new List<string>() { "model", "projection", "ambientLight", "lightDirection", "diffuse" });

                // Get geometry like plane from object files
                var geometry = Geometry.ParseObjFile(await File.ReadAllTextAsync("includes/models/plane.obj"));

               
                var texbuffer = await ArtworkProvider.GetStaticAsync(0x03AB);
                _texture = await WebGLFramework.Texture.BuildLandAsync(gl, texbuffer);


                //_texture = await WebGLFramework.Texture.BuildAsync(gl, _textureContainer.GetValueOrDefault(0), size, size);
                _cylinderMesh = await Mesh.BuildAsync(gl, geometry, _texture);
                _light = new Light();
                await DrawSceneAsync();
```

Finally my BuildLandAsync task:

```
public static async Task<Texture> BuildLandAsync(WebGLContext gl, int[] buffer, int width = 44, int height = 44)
        {
            
            var texture = await gl.CreateTextureAsync();
            await gl.BindTextureAsync(TextureType.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
            await gl.TexImage2DAsync(Texture2DType.TEXTURE_2D, 0, PixelFormat.LUMINANCE, width, height, 0, PixelFormat.LUMINANCE, PixelType.UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
            await gl.TexParameterAsync(TextureType.TEXTURE_2D, TextureParameter.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, (int)TextureParameterValue.NEAREST);
            await gl.TexParameterAsync(TextureType.TEXTURE_2D, TextureParameter.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, (int)TextureParameterValue.NEAREST);
            await gl.TexParameterAsync(TextureType.TEXTURE_2D, TextureParameter.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, (int)TextureParameterValue.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
            await gl.TexParameterAsync(TextureType.TEXTURE_2D, TextureParameter.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, (int)TextureParameterValue.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
            return new Texture(gl, texture, width, height);
        }
```

Comment: The pixel format of the texture is `PixelFormat.LUMINANCE`. "LUMINANCE" is a grayscale value. You must use a texture format with RGB information.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I picked Luminance since it was the only one which was working because the array doesn’t have enough values of the rgb or rgba struct. Means it is an ushort array of bgra5551 what I convert to argb32 int array that webgl can handle it. The error means something like that 43 bytes are needed and 44 pixels while it just contains 19 rows ( 0pixels) when setting pixel format to rgb or rgba.

Answer (score 0):

The pixel format of the texture is PixelFormat.LUMINANCE. "LUMINANCE" is a grayscale value. You must use a texture format with RGB information.
Since your pixel format is  `bgra5551`, you can hat to use `PixelType.UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_5_5_1` (see [WebGL specification - Texture objects](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/1.0/#5.14.8)):

```js
await gl.TexImage2DAsync(Texture2DType.TEXTURE_2D, 0, PixelFormat.RGBA, 
    width, height, 0, PixelFormat.RGBA, PixelType.UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_5_5_1, buffer);
```

Comment: @3HMonkey The error message is *"type UNSIGNED_SHORT but ArrayBufferView not Uint16Array"*. So `buffer` is clearly **not Uint16Array**! (If you have additional information, you need to add it to the question, but not in comments)